# wpf treeviewitem set icon in runtime

Tags: wpf

I have a treeview in a form:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treview_Menu"/>
```

I have my custom class:

```
public class CustomClass
   public property description as string
   public property icon as string
end class
```

In runtime I have:

```
dim oList as list(of CustomClass) = CustomClass_LayerLink.ListAll()
dim node as TreeViewItem

for each oEntity as CustomClass in oList
   node = new TreeViewItem with
   {
      .header = oEntity.description
   }

   me.treview_Menu.items.add(node)
next
```

How I can do to set the icon for each node added?
Thankz.

I use: visual studio ultimate 2012, and wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the source property of the image. Binding should work and so you dont need the for each loop to do it manually in wpf.

Hope it helps.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Name="icon"
                           Width="15"
                           Height="15"
                           Source="{Binding icon}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Icon is the image which is bound to icon property of Customclass and it should be the path of the image

Comment: Hi, thankz for help, it works, but now how i can launch specific windown when double click treeviewitem ¿?